# mysql update math

Tags: mysql

say p.products_price equals 1

why does:

> ```
> UPDATE products p
> SET p.products_price = (1 + p.products_price)
> WHERE p.products_id = 8
> ```

make p.products_price equals 3?

It is adding 1 to the price and then doing it all over again? I am trying to do something a little more complicated but when it didn't work I broke it down to the simplest thing ever. Can I make some kind of temporary value here and calculate the new price and then set it to that?

Please help I am raging,
Thanks.

MySQL client version: 4.1.22

edit: the column is decimal type, i tried the same update on an int column with the same result.

edit: this is not running in code so there is no chance of the code calling the same update twice

Comment: I have been having what appears to be the exact same problem although it appears that the when the webpage in question is refreshed 2 is added but on the initial load/running of the script it is adding 1 correctly. Does this give anyone a clue?

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE products    
SET products_price = (1 + products_price)    
WHERE products_id = 8
```

works like it should (removed table alias 'p')

Comment: Syntax was wrong... It was missing 'AS':
`UPDATE products AS p
SET p.products_price = (1 + p.products_price)
WHERE p.products_id = 8`

Answer (score 0):

That should definitely set products_price to 2.  There must be something else going on.

This is similar to [Problem with updating a MySQL field with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238800/problem-with-updating-a-mysql-field-with-php) but there was no good solution there so I'll leave this one open too.

Are you running it from the client, or through a script?

Do you have any transactions open or other scripts accessing the database?

Edit:  You mentioned joins in your comment - I'd be willing to bet that your join is pulling back the same row more than once.

Comment: nothing else is going on, i was first doing it through a php script, but now i am running it in phpmyadmin. the real update has a couple joins and can have some where's too.

Comment: Ahh I bet it's the joins - you must be selecting the same row more than once

Comment: no i am literally running the sql above and it still does that, even if i say 'where product_id = 200' :(

Comment: Oh.. lame... can you paste a dump of the table structure + data (or at least some of the data) and I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL looks fine.  Is the 'something' column unique?  Make sure that you are only updating a single record.

Comment: something right now is a userid. there is only one row that this update matches. it only says 1 row affected. is it possible it would update the same row twice?